# XSLT element sort via join

Tags: xml, xslt

Would like to sort the following XML by joining the `fsxml/formula/ingrrow` where `itemcode = fsxml/item` (attribute `objkey`) and having the elements named `erpplantnr_11` through `erpplantnr_30` from item moved after the last `attribute10` element for each `ingrrow`.

Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided!

(Simplifying and providing first XSLT attempt)
(Simplified example - want to move erpplantnr_11 element after attribute1 element where the attribute objkey matches the itemcode element)

Looking for help on how to create the "join".  Thanks again.

(XSLT):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 

xmlns:fsxml="http://www.FormationSystems.com" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="formula">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ingrrow"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ingrrow | item">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="itemcode"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute1"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="erpplantnr_11"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fsxml/fsxml">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Resultant XML - Need to match the two item objectkey attributes with their ingrrow itemcodes and have the output xml list the erpplantnr_11 element after the attribute1 element:

```
<fsxml>
  <formula maxcol="51" keycount="2" fmt="A" dtlcodes="HEADER\INGR" objectkey="NOR000133\0002" filteredfields="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ingrrow detail="1" fmt="X">
      <itemcode>NOR60506</itemcode> 
      <attribute1>000000000050051116</attribute1> 
    </ingrrow>
    <ingrrow detail="1" fmt="X">
      <itemcode>7K015</itemcode> 
      <attribute1>000000000000800479</attribute1> 
    </ingrrow>
  </formula>
  <item maxcol="35" keycount="1" fmt="A" dtlcodes="HEADER" objectkey="NOR60506" filteredfields="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <erpplantnr_11>121212;343434</erpplantnr_11> 
  </item>
  <item maxcol="35" keycount="1" fmt="A" dtlcodes="HEADER" objectkey="7K015" filteredfields="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <erpplantnr_11>123456</erpplantnr_11> 
  </item>
</fsxml>
```

Original XML:

```
<fsxml>
  <formula maxcol="51" keycount="2" fmt="A" dtlcodes="HEADER\INGR" objectkey="NOR000133\0002" filteredfields="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <keycode>NOR000133</keycode> 
      <keycode2>0002</keycode2> 
      <description>48782 ALABASTER WHITE MB9960 NA</description> 
      <formulaalias /> 
      <alternateformula /> 
      <timedate xsi:nil="true" /> 
      <productcode /> 
      <productdescr /> 
      <reportcode /> 
      <reportregion /> 
      <alias_code1 /> 
      <alias_code2 /> 
      <alias_code3 /> 
      <alias_code4 /> 
      <alias_code5 /> 
      <alias_code6 /> 
      <alias_code7 /> 
      <alias_code8 /> 
      <hseapacdoc /> 
      <hseemeadoc /> 
      <hsenasadoc /> 
      <wau_local_designee /> 
      <apac1_local_designee /> 
      <apac2_local_designee /> 
      <apc_local_designee /> 
      <emea_local_designee /> 
      <na_local_designee>PREST</na_local_designee> 
      <sa_local_designee /> 
      <ras_sent>Yes</ras_sent> 
      <erp_waunr /> 
      <erp_apac1nr /> 
      <erp_apac2nr /> 
      <erp_apcnr /> 
      <erp_emeanr /> 
      <erp_nornr /> 
      <erp_sanr /> 
      <crfc_code>NOR000133</crfc_code> 
      <orig_desc /> 
      <erpglobal_1 /> 
      <erpglobal_2 /> 
      <erpglobal_3 /> 
      <uomcode>KG</uomcode> 
      <itemcode>NOR000133</itemcode> 
      <yield>74.8956541853986</yield> 
      <yieldpct>100</yieldpct> 
      <phantomind>0</phantomind> 
      <primaryformulaind>1</primaryformulaind> 
      <processyield>100</processyield> 
      <projectcode /> 
      <labbookcode /> 
      <labbookpage /> 
      <ownercode>ARFTL</ownercode> 
      <groupcode>GROUP_1</groupcode> 
      <statusind>291</statusind> 
      <approvalcode /> 
      <holdcode /> 
      <workcode /> 
      <workcode2 /> 
      <formulatorcode>ARFTL</formulatorcode> 
      <yieldcalcind>1</yieldcalcind> 
      <customer>RO_NOR</customer> 
      <comment /> 
      <datemodified>2012-05-11T14:55:37</datemodified> 
      <class>PRODUCT</class> 
      <typeind>0</typeind> 
      <parentfid>42871</parentfid> 
      <mfgitemmaster>NOR000133\0002</mfgitemmaster> 
      <calcmode>0</calcmode> 
      <formulaid>728067</formulaid> 
      <adjustparam /> 
      <materialchange>1</materialchange> 
      <judgement /> 
    - <ingrrow detail="1" fmt="X">
        <lineid>1</lineid> 
        <itemcode>NOR60506</itemcode> 
        <quantity>66.6877872652848</quantity> 
        <uomcode>KG</uomcode> 
        <description>KV1348 KV1348 White Dispersion</description> 
        <materialpct>89.0409303324918</materialpct> 
        <linebreakcode /> 
        <scaleind>0</scaleind> 
        <subformulaind>0</subformulaind> 
        <formulaid>0</formulaid> 
        <componentind>1</componentind> 
        <instruction /> 
        <substituteind>0</substituteind> 
        <formulacode>NOR60506\0006</formulacode> 
        <status>401</status> 
        <class /> 
        <decdigit>0</decdigit> 
        <cas /> 
        <commcode /> 
        <aliascode1 /> 
        <aliascode2 /> 
        <aliascode3 /> 
        <aliascode4 /> 
        <activequantity>0</activequantity> 
        <relqtypct>0</relqtypct> 
        <attribute1>000000000050051116</attribute1> 
        <attribute2 /> 
        <attribute3 /> 
        <attribute4 /> 
        <attribute5 /> 
        <instrucflag>1</instrucflag> 
        <paramcode /> 
        <pvalue xsi:nil="true" /> 
        <lotcode /> 
        <aliascode5 /> 
        <aliascode6 /> 
        <aliascode7>APC 56% 5T070/3Z145 (KV1348) / P:393367</aliascode7> 
        <aliascode8 /> 
        <sectionname /> 
        <sectiontype>0</sectiontype> 
        <adjustind>0</adjustind> 
        <attribute6 /> 
        <attribute7 /> 
        <attribute8 /> 
        <attribute9 /> 
        <attribute10 /> 
      </ingrrow>
    - <ingrrow detail="1" fmt="X">
        <lineid>2</lineid> 
        <itemcode>7K015</itemcode> 
        <quantity>8.20786692011385</quantity> 
        <uomcode>KG</uomcode> 
        <description>METHYLAMYLKETONE</description> 
        <materialpct>10.9590696675082</materialpct> 
        <linebreakcode /> 
        <scaleind>0</scaleind> 
        <subformulaind>0</subformulaind> 
        <formulaid>0</formulaid> 
        <componentind>8</componentind> 
        <instruction /> 
        <substituteind>0</substituteind> 
        <status>401</status> 
        <class /> 
        <decdigit>0</decdigit> 
        <cas>110-43-0</cas> 
        <commcode /> 
        <aliascode1>S194</aliascode1> 
        <aliascode2>METHYL AMYL KETONE</aliascode2> 
        <aliascode3 /> 
        <aliascode4>METHYLAMYLKETONE</aliascode4> 
        <activequantity>0</activequantity> 
        <relqtypct>0</relqtypct> 
        <attribute1>000000000000800479</attribute1> 
        <attribute2 /> 
        <attribute3 /> 
        <attribute4 /> 
        <attribute5 /> 
        <instrucflag>1</instrucflag> 
        <paramcode /> 
        <pvalue xsi:nil="true" /> 
        <lotcode /> 
        <aliascode5>METHYLAMYLKETONE</aliascode5> 
        <aliascode6>Methylamylketon 165,5 KG</aliascode6> 
        <aliascode7>METHYL N-AMYL KETONE (Bulk)</aliascode7> 
        <aliascode8 /> 
        <sectionname /> 
        <sectiontype>0</sectiontype> 
        <adjustind>0</adjustind> 
        <attribute6 /> 
        <attribute7 /> 
        <attribute8 /> 
        <attribute9 /> 
        <attribute10 /> 
      </ingrrow>
    </formula>
  - <fsxml>
    - <item maxcol="35" keycount="1" fmt="A" dtlcodes="HEADER" objectkey="NOR60506" filteredfields="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <keycode>NOR60506</keycode> 
        <description>KV1348 White Dispersion</description> 
        <rmremark /> 
        <ras_sent /> 
        <erp_waunr /> 
        <erp_apac1nr /> 
        <erp_apac2nr /> 
        <erp_apcnr /> 
        <erp_emeanr /> 
        <erp_nornr>000000000050051116</erp_nornr> 
        <erp_sanr /> 
        <erpglobal_1 /> 
        <erpglobal_2 /> 
        <erpglobal_3 /> 
        <erpplantnr_11>121212;343434</erpplantnr_11> 
        <erpplantnr_12 /> 
        <erpplantnr_13 /> 
        <erpplantnr_14 /> 
        <erpplantnr_15 /> 
        <erpplantnr_16 /> 
        <erpplantnr_17 /> 
        <erpplantnr_18 /> 
        <erpplantnr_19 /> 
        <erpplantnr_20 /> 
        <erpplantnr_21 /> 
        <erpplantnr_22 /> 
        <erpplantnr_23 /> 
        <erpplantnr_24 /> 
        <erpplantnr_25 /> 
        <erpplantnr_26 /> 
        <erpplantnr_27 /> 
        <erpplantnr_28 /> 
        <erpplantnr_29 /> 
        <erpplantnr_30 /> 
        <uomcode>KG</uomcode> 
        <calcind>0</calcind> 
        <scaleind>0</scaleind> 
        <statusind>401</statusind> 
        <approvalcode /> 
        <class /> 
        <componentind>1</componentind> 
        <linebreakcode /> 
        <holdcode /> 
        <formulacode>NOR60506</formulacode> 
        <version>0006</version> 
        <cas /> 
        <commcode /> 
        <aliascode1 /> 
        <aliascode2 /> 
        <aliascode3 /> 
        <aliascode4 /> 
        <aliascode5 /> 
        <aliascode6 /> 
        <aliascode7>APC 56% 5T070/3Z145 (KV1348) / P:393367</aliascode7> 
        <aliascode8 /> 
        <threshold>0</threshold> 
        <datemodified>2012-04-28T19:50:12</datemodified> 
        <ftypeind>0</ftypeind> 
        <judgement /> 
      </item>
      - <item maxcol="35" keycount="1" fmt="A" dtlcodes="HEADER" objectkey="7K015" filteredfields="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <keycode>7K015</keycode> 
        <description>METHYLAMYLKETONE</description> 
        <rmremark /> 
        <ras_sent /> 
        <erp_waunr>S194</erp_waunr> 
        <erp_apac1nr>00000000000007K015</erp_apac1nr> 
        <erp_apac2nr /> 
        <erp_apcnr>7K015</erp_apcnr> 
        <erp_emeanr>000000000000800479</erp_emeanr> 
        <erp_nornr>000000000000800479</erp_nornr> 
        <erp_sanr /> 
        <erpglobal_1 /> 
        <erpglobal_2 /> 
        <erpglobal_3 /> 
        <erpplantnr_11>123456</erpplantnr_11> 
        <erpplantnr_12>234567</erpplantnr_12> 
        <erpplantnr_13>345678</erpplantnr_13> 
        <erpplantnr_14>456789</erpplantnr_14> 
        <erpplantnr_15>567890</erpplantnr_15> 
        <erpplantnr_16>678901</erpplantnr_16> 
        <erpplantnr_17>789012</erpplantnr_17> 
        <erpplantnr_18>890123</erpplantnr_18> 
        <erpplantnr_19>901234</erpplantnr_19> 
        <erpplantnr_20>012345</erpplantnr_20> 
        <erpplantnr_21>654321</erpplantnr_21> 
        <erpplantnr_22>765432</erpplantnr_22> 
        <erpplantnr_23>876543</erpplantnr_23> 
        <erpplantnr_24>987654</erpplantnr_24> 
        <erpplantnr_25>098765</erpplantnr_25> 
        <erpplantnr_26>109876</erpplantnr_26> 
        <erpplantnr_27>210987</erpplantnr_27> 
        <erpplantnr_28>321098</erpplantnr_28> 
        <erpplantnr_29>432109</erpplantnr_29> 
        <erpplantnr_30>543210</erpplantnr_30> 
        <uomcode>KG</uomcode> 
        <calcind>0</calcind> 
        <scaleind>0</scaleind> 
        <statusind>401</statusind> 
        <approvalcode /> 
        <class /> 
        <componentind>8</componentind> 
        <linebreakcode /> 
        <holdcode /> 
        <formulacode /> 
        <version /> 
        <cas>110-43-0</cas> 
        <commcode /> 
        <aliascode1>S194</aliascode1> 
        <aliascode2>METHYL AMYL KETONE</aliascode2> 
        <aliascode3 /> 
        <aliascode4>METHYLAMYLKETONE</aliascode4> 
        <aliascode5>METHYLAMYLKETONE</aliascode5> 
        <aliascode6>Methylamylketon 165,5 KG</aliascode6> 
        <aliascode7>METHYL N-AMYL KETONE (Bulk)</aliascode7> 
        <aliascode8 /> 
        <threshold>0</threshold> 
        <datemodified>2012-04-24T22:52:56</datemodified> 
        <ftypeind>0</ftypeind> 
        <judgement /> 
      </item>
    </fsxml>
  </fsxml>
```

Comment: what did you try? ideally, you would indicate the work you have done and where you got stuck. It would also help if you could simplify your input to be illustrative while still being a valid representation of your problem as well as the expected transformation result.

Comment: I am a newbie - tried overlaying apply-templates on the identity template but can't figure out how to nest from two different parent nodes and how to join an attribute value (objectkey) from the second parent (item) to an element value (itemcode) on the first parent (ingrrow).  So one example would be match item 7K015 to the second ingrrow and move its erpplantnr_11 element to after the attribute10 element.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still kind of hard for me to understand what exactly you need but I hope this will help you get going.

I assumed you want to copy the input XML but instead of copying over the `item`s alongside the  `ingrrow`s, you rather want to take out those `erpplantnr_` elements from the corresponding `item` and put them right after the last `attribute` child node of the `ingrrow`.

While we can do an inline lookup in our XPath predicates it's a good idea to look at the [`xsl:key` and `fn:key()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key) as a better way to express a lookup:

```
<xsl:key name="items" match="/fsxml/fsxml/item" use="@objectkey"/>
```

This one will "index" all `item`s by the `@objectkey`. Next, let's put the identity transform in there, just like you had it:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Next, let's silent the `item` since we said we only need to pull out something of a matching `item` to be displayed elsewhere:

```
<xsl:template match="item"/>
```

Finally, let's intercept that last `attribute` node and inject the matching `erpplantnr_` nodes right after it:

```
<xsl:template match="ingrrow/*[contains(local-name(), 'attribute')][last()]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('items', current()/parent::*/itemcode)/*[contains(local-name(), 'erpplantnr_')]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Here we copy that last `attribute` node and then use the key to lookup a matching `item` node from which we enumerate all `erpplantnr_` in the order of their occurrence in the document.

I am not sure how generic or specific you wanted those selectors to be so I picked a place in the middle.

When I run this transform on your input document I get a copy of it in return without the `item` nodes but with the corresponding `erpplantnr_` copied right after that `attribute10` node in each `ingrrow`.

Hope it helps.

p.s. full transform listing just in case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:fsxml="http://www.FormationSystems.com" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="items" match="/fsxml/fsxml/item" use="@objectkey"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item"/>

    <xsl:template match="ingrrow/*[contains(local-name(), 'attribute')][last()]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('items', current()/parent::*/itemcode)/*[contains(local-name(), 'erpplantnr_')]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Pavel, thanks so much for the response - works great!  I really appreciate the use and explanation of the xsl:key.  That will prove very helpful throughout the project.